# Site URL does not accept uni.me TLD

Tags: facebook, comments, facebook-apps

Since I am using facebook comment plugin in my personal wordpress blog, I had to create a facebook app for comment plugin to work.

I just faced the problem that facebook apps integration does not accept **uni.me** TLD however it accept **.com** TLD which give me an error message

```
Error
There was a problem saving your changes. Please try again later.
```

Is any idea to get this fixed. It seems that problem had been started after some facebook developer platform update since I was able to use .uni.me TLD earlier but when I deactivated my account after removing the app and recreated the app again with new facebook account it showed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. The first possibility is that you are not using proper DNS to point domain to page, but rather url forwarding, or iframe. Usually for the case of 2nd level domain.
2. Another possibility is that in your html code, the meta data is not defined properly or correctly:

   > `<meta property='og:url'> content="[link-has-to-be-the-same-as-in-fb-app]"/>`
3. Or maybe, Facebook has just blocked the domain like [Google did](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/CYJih44r6Ps)